# Stripe Payment Integration

Tags: magento2, stripe

I am integrating stripe with Magento 2 but the stripe is not working properly. We have multi-website and on the 1st site, the stripe is showing and working properly but on the 2nd site stripe payment gateway is not showing.

Please help me

Comment: Any error on console or error log file?

Comment: there is no error and console log

Comment: please check that payment method is enabled or not for specific website in store configuration

Comment: I checked and its enabled for all the websites in admin and core_config_data table both.

Comment: Are you using store codes added to the url to distinguish between websites or separate domains for each website? I'd check the webhook link configured in Stripe dashboard first.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible reasons for the payment method to not show at the checkout:

- Newer versions of the module depend on specific versions of the Stripe PHP library. You can check which version you have installed from vendor/stripe/stripe-php/VERSION. If you have an old version, you should see a yellow admin notification in your Magento admin area.
- The Stripe API keys may not have been configured correctly from the module configuration section. This would also display as a warning in the admin.
- You may have configured the module to only display for specific countries.

Comment: I checked all the points . PHP library is already installed and I checked API key configure correctly and payment method  is showing for all the countries . Warning is not coming in the admin panel.

Comment: Do you have any other configuration such as Minimum Order Amount, or GeoIP modules that might hide payment methods at your checkout? If not, you should contact the developer of the Stripe module.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
I have resolved the issues.. Issues is due to 3rd party extension

Comment: @Aish could you please share which extension caused it so that others can also benefit from the answer?